# Create page break using OpenXml

Tags: c#, .net, openxml, openxml-sdk

I use OpenXml to create Word document with simple text and some tables under this text. How can I force Paragraph with this text to show always on new page? Maybe this paragraph should be some Header but I'm not sure how to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can create a page break within a Run element using the `<w:br>` element. In raw OpenXML, it would look something like:

```
<w:p>
  <w:r>
    <w:br w:type="page" />
  </w:r>
</w:p>
```

If you're using the OpenXml SDK, you can use

```
new Paragraph(
  new Run(
    new Break(){ Type = BreakValues.Page }));
```

EDIT:

If you just want to specify that a paragraph is the last thing on a page, you can try the `<w:lastRenderedPageBreak />` tag.

```
new Paragraph(
   new Run(
      new LastRenderedPageBreak(),
      new Text("Last text on the page")));
```

Comment: I try this solution but I have problem if some data before my page break fill previous page. Word will add page break, then my code creates another page break and I have one empty page. :/ I'm not sure how to change this :/

Comment: The part of this answer about `w:br/@w:type="page"` is fine, but the part about `w:lastRenderedPageBreak` is incorrect.  `w:lastRenderedPageBreak` should only be inserted by processors that have determined where a rendered page break ***did*** occur; it does not specify where a page break ***should*** occur.

Answer (score 15):

The PageBreakBefore property accomplishes this. It will insert a page break before your paragraph if Word didn't insert one automatically.

```
if (myParagraph.ParagraphProperties== null) 
{ 
    myParagraph.ParagraphProperties = new ParagraphProperties();
}

myParagraph.ParagraphProperties.PageBreakBefore = new PageBreakBefore();
```

I believe it looks something like this in Open XML:

```
  <w:p>
    <w:pPr>
      ...
      <w:pageBreakBefore/>   
      ...
    </w:pPr>
    ...    
  </w:p>
```