# Adding new page in word with OpenXML

Tags: c#, sharepoint, ms-word, openxml

I am looking for a way to dynamically insert pages in MS Word: one as page 1 and one page as last page. I have found many samples for inserting spreadsheets and slides in Excel and PowerPoint, but none yet for insert pages in a WordprocessingDocument using OpenXML. If you got any samples of inserting pages in Word with OpenXML, please provide :)

Answer (score 2):

Only way to manage pages is to use pagebreaks. This  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795315/create-page-break-using-openxml) has code samples to help you to insert pages

Comment: Hi Udaya. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. If you know about more detaling samples where I can insert a blank page at the start and at the end of a document, please do post it.